# Undefined constant ABSPATH

Tags: php, errors

Only when I access the main url does this WordPress error appear and the content I edited does not appear

[image]

I looked in the error.log file and the following error appears

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "ABSPATH" in /home3/agen9607/daniellebachadermatologia.com.br/wp-settings.php:33
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home3/agen9607/daniellebachadermatologia.com.br/wp-settings.php on line 33
```

Now I ask you, how do I change this inside the folder?

What do I need to type and where?

I would really appreciate anyone who can help me resolve this issue.

Comment: can you edit this to clearly state the question? You ask us to explain it as if you were a 5 year old but never told us what it was you needed us to explain. Use the edit link under the tags. Also have you been modifying files in `wp-includes`/`wp-admin` or files that start with `wp-`?

Comment: I want to know how to fix the error on this wordpress page, and what code to replace on line 33

Comment: you would _never_ modify `wp-settings.php` under any circumstances. As for the error if i visit the page I get a tonne of mixed content warnings in the browsers error console, everything needs to be `https` not `http`. If you have made any modifications to core WordPress files you need to undo them immediatley

Comment: So, how i fix the error in url that is in the post?

Comment: I mentioned there are mixed content warnings in the browser console, you need to fix those first, and by doing that your homepage might look more like how it's supposed to. Right now there's very very little information in your question that could be used to tell you how though, no details on how you implemented SSL/HTTPS, and no code to work with :(

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.